# Why was the imaging of M87 black hole easier than imaging the Milky way's Sagittarius A*?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, radio, imaging, milky-way

In the recent EHT press release of the image of the super massive black hole at M87, I am curious to know why the super massive black hole at the centre of milky way has not been imaged yet.

Answer (score 0):

The EHT needs a long exposure time. M87* is rather stable, so while SgrA* is apparently quite variable even during exposure time. The team is busy de blurring the SgrA* image. See this link and practice your Dutch at the same time: https://www.astroblogs.nl/2019/04/10/een-opzienbarend-eht-middagje-in-brussel/amp/